# Creating a single video using extracted frames from several video clips without having to write the frames into a folder

Tags: bash, ffmpeg

I have a set of mp4 video clips named: `file1.mp4, file2.mp4,..filen.mp4.`
I want to write a code for going through the files sequentially and extracting a frame every 10 seconds of the video.
Then I want to combine the frames and make one output video file at 6 fps.

I have the code which does that but it extracts frames and stores them in a subfolder before combining them into a video. I think that is inefficient.
Is there a way whereby I can extract frames from the video clips and output the final video without having to store the frames in a folder?

This is the code that I have.

```
#!/bin/bash

# Step 1: Extract frames every 10 seconds
input_folder="/home/aj/Videos/merge"
output_folder="/home/aj/Videos/merge"
subfolder="frames"

# Create subfolder if it doesn't exist
mkdir -p "$output_folder/$subfolder"

# Get the total number of input files
total_files=$(find "$input_folder" -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "*.mp4" | wc -l)
processed_files=0
global_frame_counter=0

# Iterate through mp4 files in the input folder
for file in "$input_folder"/*.mp4; do
  filename=$(basename "$file")
  filename_no_ext="${filename%.mp4}"

  # Extract frames every 10 seconds
  ffmpeg -i "$file" -vf fps=1/10 "$output_folder/$subfolder/output_${global_frame_counter}%02d.png"
  
    # Increment the global frame counter
  ((global_frame_counter ++))

  # Increment the processed files count
  ((processed_files++))

  # Calculate and echo the percentage of files processed
  percentage=$((processed_files * 100 / total_files))
  echo -e "\033[1;32mProcessing: $percentage% complete\033[0m"
done

# Step 2: Combine frames into a single video
cd "$output_folder/$subfolder" || exit

ffmpeg -r 6 -f image2 -s 1920x1080 -i "output_%*.png" -vcodec libx264 -crf 25 -pix_fmt yuv420p "$output_folder/result.mp4"

echo "Frames extracted and video created successfully."
```

Comment: I don't work with `ffmpeg` so fwiw ... web searches on 'ffmpeg write to stdout' and 'ffmpeg read from stdin' bring up a lot of hits that may be of use; general idea ... `for file in *mp4; do ffmpeg -i "$file" -vf fps=1/10 -f mp4; done | ffmpeg -r 6 -f image2 -s 1920x1080 -i -  ...`; for internal `ffmpeg` replace output file name with `-f <output_format>`; output from `while` loop is piped to 2nd `ffmpeg` where input is `-i -`; one issue: you'll need to refrain from issuing `echo/printf` commands from within the `while` loop else they'll be fed to the outer `ffmpeg`

Comment: @markp-fuso You are trying to come up with an answer and posting it here in the comment section. Don't do that. Post it as an answer and, if it doesn't work, you can always delete it.

Comment: It's the same on efficiency.  If the processed frames are in a buffer vs. a tmp, it's no different.  They have to go somewhere.